# PDO request to loop in a field

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

First, I know the structure is not the best but I need to live with this.

Table `___Products`

```
|--------|----------|----------------|
| PRO_Id | PRO_Name | PRO_LinkedProd |
|--------|----------|----------------|
|      1 |   Banana |          2,3,4 |
|      2 |    Apple |            1,3 |
|      3 |     Pear |              3 |
|      4 |   Cherry |          1,2,3 |
|--------|----------|----------------|
```

I'm looking to loop in `PRO_LinkedProd` for one product (Ex: Banana).

Desired output for `Banana` should be:

```
|--------|----------|
| PRO_Id | PRO_Name |
|--------|----------|
|      2 |    Apple |
|      3 |     Pear |
|      4 |   Cherry |
|--------|----------|
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(PRO_LinkedProd), ",") as list_prods 
FROM ___Products p 
INNER JOIN ___Products p ON p.PRO_LinkedProd like concat("%", p.PRO_Id, "%")
GROUP BY PRO_Id
ORDER BY PRO_Id ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
select p.*
from ___Products p
inner join ( select PRO_LinkedProd
             from ___Products
             where PRO_Name ='Banana'
           )  x on x.PRO_LinkedProd   like concat("%",p.PRO_Id, "%");
```

In the subquery you get the PRO_LinkedProd where PRO_Name equal to Banana and use that result as a join condition with ___Products table.

https://dbfiddle.uk/nMmDm32e

> First, I know the structure is not the best but I need to live with
> this.

If possible, you must fix the design to save a lot of future pain.

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)